# Laravel route being stuck in UTF-8

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, routes

i have this controller to redirect:

```
$zone='لندن';
$type='خانه';

return redirect()->route('searchResult',['zone' => $request->zone , 'type' => $request->type]);
```

**and here is my route:**

```
Route::get('/estates/{zone}/{type}', 'EstateController@searchResult')->name('searchResult');
```

When Its Redirect I get a URL like this-

```
http://localhost:8000/estates/لندن/خانه
```

Instead of above I would like to have this URL-

```
http://localhost:8000/estates/خانه/لندن
```

i don't wanna switch the route parameters!
need help ty!

**Edited:**
i have this route : 
`/estates/{zone}`
and wanna this route 
`/estates/{zone}/{type}` be a sub-route for base route
but its return me a reverse route and its not going friendly! and its why i dont wanna change the route parameters!

Comment: Just switch `{type}` and `{zone}` in your route definition?

Comment: cant dud! its change my plan for another route!
i write don't wanna switch route parameters!

Comment: `['zone' => $request->zone , 'type' => $request->type]` seems to be doing what it's supposed to. Why not just swap type and zone there?

Comment: cuse i have another route http://localhost:8000/estates/{zone}/ and i wanna this route:/estates/{zone}/{type} be a sub-route for base route!

Comment: Can you go through your question again and try to update it in a way that makes the problem more clear?

Comment: Yes! i edit my q!

Comment: Can we see both of your Routes, which one is place before the other, the name of the first Route with no type?

Comment: Do you want it to be 2 Routes or the same Route with `{type}` as an optional parameter?

Comment: @KeitelDOG no dud i just want to know why its change my route from this http://localhost:8000/estates/لندن/خانه to this http://localhost:8000/estates/خانه/لندن when i route like this
`$zone='لندن';
$type='خانه';
Route::get('/estates/{zone}/{type}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your exact behavior, but Laravel has something to handle better those kind of Sub Parameters that is Optional Parameters. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Define a single Route, and put `?` after your parameter name to make it optional:

```
Route::get('/estates/{zone}/{type?}', 'EstateController@searchResult')->name('searchResult');
```

And in your Action method signature, put type parameter as optional too

```
<?php

public function searchResult($zone, $type=null)
{
    echo $zone.' / '.$type;

    /*if(!$type) {
        $type = 'commune';

        return redirect()->route('searchResult',['zone' => request()->zone , 'type' => $type]);
    }*/

}
```

And in your case I don't really see a reason to pass `request()->type` as parameter to route, because even if it's null or not, you will remain in the same state. If you have a new `$type` variable in your code, then pass it as :

```
return redirect()->route('searchResult',['zone' => request()->zone , 'type' => $type]);
```

**EDIT -------**

If your code in Controller is really :

```
$zone='لندن';
$type='خانه';

return redirect()->route('searchResult',['zone' => $request->zone , 'type' => $request->type]);
```

Then I think you should use `$zone` and `$type` variable instead of request parameters value :

```
$zone='لندن';
$type='خانه';

return redirect()->route('searchResult',['zone' => $zone , 'type' => $type]);
```